# Why this function defines a bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Show that if $B\subset A$ and there is an injective function $f:A\to B$, then $\operatorname{card}(A)=\operatorname{card}(B)$.

This exercise suggest a way to solve the problem: define $A_1=A, B_1=B$ and $A_n=f(A_{n-1}),B_n=f(B_{n-1})$. Since $A \subset B$ we have $A_{n+1}\subset B_n\subset A_{n-1}$ for $n\geq2$.

Then define $$h(x) =  \left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{l}
     f(x) &\text{ if } x \in A_n-B_n \text{ for some n}\\
     x &\text{ otherwise } \\
  \end{array}
  \right.$$

And the above function is supposed to define a bijection, but I cannot see why the function is injective, I mean, why isn't this possible:

[image]

I imagine the problem about injectivity as in the picture I draw, $x\in A_1 - B_1$ then $h(x)=f(x)=y$, but since $y\notin A_n-B_n$ for any $n$ and $y\in A$ must be $h(y)=y$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your picture, if $f(x)=y\in B_2$, then $x$ has to be in $f^{-1}(B_2) = B$, so your $x\notin A_1-B_1$.

You can probably generalise this a bit to get a proof for injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to suggest an alternative solution.I will use [Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem).

$B\subset A\Rightarrow g:B\to A$ by $g(x)=x$  $\forall x \in B$ is an injection.
Also given that $f:A\to B$ is an injection.

Thus by Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem we conclude that there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

hence $card(A)=card(B)$

**NOTE:** According to OP and user18921 , the question actually leads to prove Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem.

Comment: I took this exercise from Munkres (Ch.7, Ex.6), this is the first part of it and prove Bernstein-Shroeder is the second one, so I can't use that theorem here :(

Comment: ok,I understand

Comment: (-1) The problem is to *prove* CBS. Assuming CBS defies the point, even if its in a slightly different form.

Comment: @user18921 sorry.I admit the fault.What do you suggest then?should I keep this post or delete it?

Comment: Perhaps change it to a comment? I think it is useful for the OP to know that this is a famous theorem (in modified form).

Comment: or adding any information in my post?what will be better?

Comment: I have made an edit to my post and added the information